# binding.pry ignored by rspec

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, pry, rspec3, pry-rails

I am expecting a pry session to be opened in my console during execution of `rspec`. Am I doing something incorrect? Or expecting the wrong behavior?

Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  ...
  gem 'pry-rails'
  ...
end
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
...
pry (0.10.0)
...
rspec-rails (3.0.1)
```

spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Account, type: :model, do
  let!(:acct) { FactoryGirl.create(:account) }

  describe '#hash' do
    it 'should ...' do
      acct.property = 5
      binding.pry
      expect(acct).to_not be_nil
    end
  end

end
```

console:

```
% rspec
...
Failed examples: 
...
Randomized with seed 59654
```

Comment: gem 'pry-rescue' does the trick,  but I would still like to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you positive that spec is running? You have 3 specs in your output -- maybe the file isn't named _spec.rb or something unusually like that? Just to make sure I'd try a puts "should open pry" or similar right before that just as a check for something crazy :)

Comment: Could you make a minimal reproducible app on somewhere for people to clone and investigate further? Thanks!

Comment: @juanitofatas no... I'm sorry. I haven't used ruby in almost a year.

Comment: @EricFrancis No worries!

Comment: Are you sure you are getting past the `acct.property = 5`` statement?

Comment: Have you tried `require 'pry'`?

Comment: I am using byebug gem and it works fine during tests. You need only include 
  gem 'byebug' in Gemfile and call "debugger" at the point you want to debug